# localhost:8080 is not loaded for Node.js on Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, apache, server

I'm following a tutorial for Node.js and i have the code below:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response){
        request.on("end", function() {
                response.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
                });
                response.end('Hello HTTP!');
        });
}).listen(8080);
```

I have saved that code as http.js. When I try to check localhost:8080 nothing happens, only waiting. However, when I try entering localhost I see dummy "It works!" message. Probably something is running in my computer too. How can I get rid of it? I have tried stopping apache and deleting everything in /Library/WebServer/Documents.

Comment: Try to change the port and if it works on the new port...You probably didn't kill a previous running process. If you restart your machine you should be able to make it work without changing the port.

Comment: I have tried some different ports but it did not work.

Comment: It did not work, but why? What's the error message? What do you see?

Comment: Anyway, if I am not wrong, in your request handler, you need to have a routing table, i.e. call routes' handlers depending on the requested route...Could you please link to the tutorial you're watching?

Comment: @nbro I've restarted the computer but nothing changed. I start the Node by typing `node http.js` and when I try to enter _localhost:8080_ it seems trying to load. I do not any error message. When I kill `node http.js` process by using _CTRL+C_ it is seen "Failed to open page" immediately. I can see "It works" crap when I enter localhost everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer( function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080);
```

Thats a simple http server in nodeJS.

"It works!"   is the default index.html of successful installed/Running Apache http server, by default which runs on port 80. and your nodejs server is listening on port 8080,  so there there is no problem  and both can co-exist.

by any chance if you still want to stop apache server

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

can be used.

and if there is any server running on port 8080, and then you try to start your http server on port 8080, you will receive `Error: listen EADDRINUSE`
 if, your server starts without this error, you can be sure that, nothing else is running on port 8080

EDIT:
`request.on(end)` is fired when the request from client(browser) ends. but in your case browser is still waiting for your response and the request is pending.  as soon as you call `response.end()`,  immediately, the   `request.on(end)` will be triggered.

now i will modify your code, to work this way, with small modification

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response){
        response.end('Hello HTTP!');  //change
        request.on("end", function() {
                //should be outside or removed
                /*response.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
                });*/

        });
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: What can be the problem?

Comment: did you try the sample http server code i provided ?

Comment: yes it did work but what's the problem with my code? The differences are the `const` and `request.on` method.

Comment: I have changed the end method as you said but not removed writeHead method. It worked. In that case I'm throwing the tutorial I have been following to the thrash?

Answer (score -1):

Try `response.send()` instead of `response.end()`.

You are not sending information back to the client.

See: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

**EDIT**

Comment is correct, sorry. Reading too fast.

See: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener

You need a route to receive. Use `http.get('/', someFn)`

Comment: Thanks but no it does not solve. Should I install Express?

Comment: Wrong. This is not express, but plain raw node.